# update_options not updating wp_options table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am making a form for the admin area of WordPress. Here is the code so far;

```
<form method="post" action=options.php">
<?php update_option('gpspl_options', $gpspl_options);?>
<input type="text" name="gpspl_options" value="$gpspl_options"/>
<input type="submit" value="Save Changes"/>
</form>
```

On the page in the admin area the text box is auto filled with "$gpspl_options". However when I add the text and hit submit it does not update the wp_options table in the database.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your form action is set to `options.php`. What's in that file?

Comment: I have not looked in the file options.php or added anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

You always call `update_option()` on whatever is stored in `$gpspl_options`. You never do anything with the posted value (`$_POST['gpspl_options']`). So the posted value never gets saved. If you want to save the posted value, you need something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['gpspl_options'])) {
    update_option('gpspl_options', $_POST['gpspl_options']);
}
```

As for the text field, you always initialize the text field to the literal string "$gpspl_options" (not the value of the variable `$gpspl_options`). To use the value, you need something like this:

```
<?php
$gpspl_options = isset($_POST['gpspl_options']) ? $_POST['gpspl_options'] : '';
?>
<input type="text" name="gpspl_options" value="<?php echo $gpspl_options; ?>"/>
```

You might want to read an introductory PHP tutorial covering variables, variable names, output, and so on.

That said, all this mixing of logic and output is not good practice. It's what Wordpress does and therefore kind of encourages, but that doesn't mean you should do it, too.

Comment: I tried adding this code to the form and it still does not update the wp_options table. Believe me my mind is about to explode with the amount of PHP I have been reading so far that is where I got the code from. This is what it currently looks like; `<form method="post" action=options.php">
   <?php if (isset($_POST['gpspl_options'])) {
    update_option('gpspl_options', $_POST['gpspl_options']);
}?>
    <input type="text" name="gpspl_options" value="$gpspl_options"/>
 <input type="submit" value="Save Changes"/>
   </form>`

Comment: @stpetedesign You still need to update your `input` field. You're going to be showing the same value there, no matter what is in the database, because you're showing a literal string (`$` followed by `gpspl_options`), not the contents of a variable.

Comment: @stpetedesign By the way, I have been assuming that this page is `options.php`. If it's not, then your `update_option()` never gets a posted value to work on. Try adding `var_dump($_POST);` before your form to be sure.